# Check syntax of (C or Java code) in prolog

Tags: parsing, prolog, swi-prolog

i am working on a project to check Syntax of a a program Written in C or java and return the Syntax is **True** or **False**

the program that will check the below Ex. if i write it right or wrong

Ex:

```
for(x=0;x<10;x++)
{

  print("Hello");
}
```

any idea?

Comment: *any idea?*: Study the [tag:dcg] formalism first. The complete C or Java syntax is certainly a non-trivial project. Start with expression syntax **only**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a C (or Java) parser in Prolog. Just google `prolog parser` and you will get a bunch of interesting links.

Comment: Really thanks, it was hard to know what i should search for ..i found many examples
Thanks Pablo